# How to pass credentials to WCF service hosted on azure using jquery?

Tags: jquery, wcf, azure

I have hosted WCF service on my azure site and now i am trying to consume it using jquery.
I need to know how should i pass azure site credentials to service? i am trying ways but still getting access denied. In console application i was able to pull data and also insert data into azure SQL server table using service refernce (my WCF have two operation contracts). Trying the same with jquery.

Here jquery code where i am passing creds:

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "GET",   
    dataType: "json",
    url:"http://myazuresite.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc/GetToolsByAuthor",
    data: '{ author: ToolAuthor }',
    beforeSend : function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 
        getcreds(user, pass));
    },
    processData: true,
    success: function (data) {  
        alert('data retreived');                
    },              
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});

function getcreds(username, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    return tok;
}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Basic Authentication?

Comment: I am not specifying any authentication mode here. using basicHttpBinding in config file. It's a cross domain request and i have set jQuery.support.cors = true; in jquery. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you add your `<system.serviceModel>` configuration?

Comment: Hi just to update you, i have created service with webHttpBinding configuration this service works well when hosted local; Now when hosted on azure site , i was able to see data in server response and i am doing this with jsonp but at script level getting error like "Jquery was not called" , not sure how to add callback at WCF service method.